# Compare different types in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

`From what I've read, python 2 allows comparing with different types, but for some reason, python 3 has removed that. Regardless of whether or not it is a good idea to do so, I want to compare two arbitrary values, either of the same type or different. 
I read that in python 2 comparing different types is done by comparing the name of the type, so I tried to implement this.

```
def less_than_or_equal(a, b):
    if type(a) == type(b):
        return a <= b
    else:
        return str(type(a)) <= str(type(b))
```

After I did this, I realized that some types that normally would get compared like a float and an int won't compare right using this.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You could `try` the comparison and then fall back on type strings:

```
def leq(a,b):
    try:
        return a <= b
    except TypeError:
        return str(type(a)) <= str(type(b))
```

Comment: Note that `None` is always sorted first in Python 2, and numeric types are sorted before everything else (None < numbers < everything else).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against attempting this, as the 2.x behaviour is widely considered a mistake. But if you simply must emulate it...

In 2.7, the default/fallback comparison rules are as follows ([source code citation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Objects/object.c#l778)):

1. `None` compares less than anything else.
2. Numeric values compare less than non-numeric values (except `None`). This is implemented by special-casing as if they had an empty-string type name, which compares less than any other string type name. Note here that we are talking about the case where ordinary numeric comparison already failed (for example, between two `complex` values).
3. Everything else compares according to its type name, then its address if they are the same type.

Here is a 3-way comparison routine that should emulate the 2.x behaviour in 3.x:

```
from numbers import Number

def typename_or_blank(x):
    return '' if isinstance(x, Number) else type(x).__name__

def python2_cmpkey(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return 0
    try:
        return -1 if x < y else 1
    except TypeError:
        if type(x) is type(y):
            return id(x) - id(y)
        if x is None:
            return -1
        if y is None:
            return 1
        return -1 if typename_or_blank(x) < typename_or_blank(y) else 1
```

To get the `less_than_or_equal` from the question, simply compare if the result is `<= 0`. To get a usable sort key for `sorted`, `min`, `max` etc., simply wrap with `functools.cmp_to_key`.